# Baku-Tbilisi train

Tags: trains, georgia-country, tbilisi, azerbaijan, baku

I'm going to take the Baku-Tbilisi Train this summer, and would like to know if the Train stops at the Samgori Station in Tbilisi?

If not, where does it stop between Rustavi and Tbilisi central Station?

In the Azerbaijan railways booking System, it says the Train stops in Rustavi at 09:56, then at "Tbilisi-Uzl" at 10:30, and then "Tbilisi-pass" at 10:45. I suppose "Tbilisi-pass" is the central Station.

Does anyone know what Station "Tbilisi-Uzl" is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the designation of the train it is unlikely that [Georgian Railway system](http://www.railway.ge) will give you anything different than the Azerbaijan's Railway booking system so there are no other stops between Rustavi and Tbilisi.

As far as Tbilisi-Uzl is concerned it actually is short for "Тбилиси Узловая" (Tbilisi Hub for lack of better translation) which is a name for a [Navtlugi station(Russian)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8_(%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)) which actually is currently being [reconstructed](http://www.railway.ge/?web=0&action=page&p_id=284&lang=eng) for a better passenger use.

Comment: Alright, so Rustavi, Navtlugi, and Tbilisi central then?

Could you help me find Navtlugi Station on a map?

Comment: @Crazydre Look for 6km station google maps

Comment: Super, thanks very much!

Apparently 6 km from the Ortachala bus Station. Do you know how much a taxi should cost on that route? (my other Option is bus 72)

Comment: @Crazydre No I don't.